# ¿Cómo puedo añadir una cadena a una línea concreta?

Tags: bash, shell-script, sed

Tengo el siguiente `fichero.txt` que sigue el mismo patrón y quiero modificarlo en donde este ese fichero añadiendo una ip:

```
# gfhfhgfh
gfhfghgfhgfhgfh
MACs 
# Permitimos acceso a consola
USER CONSOLA *,!10.249.247.3,!10.249.245.65
/bin/false
```

Quiero modificarlo en 5 servidores a  la vez añadiendo una IP con `,!` al final de esa línea:

```
USER CONSOLA *,!10.249.247.4,!10.249.245.65,!10.249.245.90,
```

He intentado con este comando pero me lo agrega al principio

```
grep -wEi "USER CONSOLA" fichero.txt | sed -ne 's/$/,!10.249.245.90/p'
```

Con este comando agrego a todo el documento al final de cada la linea la ip, pero necesito que se agrege solo a la linea que contiene User:

```
sed 's/\r\?$/,!10.249.245.90/' fichero.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El tema aquí está en sustituir una cadena en aquella línea que tiene un patrón determinado.

El patrón es que empiece por "USER CONSOLA", por lo que debemos filtrar esa línea:

```
/^USER CONSOLA/
```

Efectivamente, si decimos:

```
sed -n '/^USER CONSOLA/p' fichero
```

Solo imprimirá esta línea.

Ahora, el tema es añadir texto al final de esta línea. Para ello utilizamos el estándar `sed 's/busca/sustituye/' fichero`. En este caso, lo que buscaremos es `$` para indicar final de línea y lo sustituiremos por la cadena a añadir:

```
sed 's/$/,!10.249.245.90,/' fichero
```

Todo junto:

```
sed '/^USER CONSOLA/s/$/,!10.249.245.90,/' fichero
```

Cuando ejecutes esto verás cómo sale el resultado por pantalla. Si quieres que el fichero se edite, usa `sed '...' fichero > nuevo_fichero && mv nuevo_fichero fichero` o `sed -i.bak '...' fichero` para que haga el cambio en el mismo fichero, generando un backup previamente.